# Open html page in a popup window (not in a new window but in the same window)

Tags: html

I am doing my final year project for my computer course and I am having trouble opening an HTML page in a new popup window.
Through googling, I have been able to open the popup but it is opening in a new window.  I want it to open in the same window like a popup without a new window.
What code do I have to use? Or do you have any suggestions involving JQuery?

Comment: Could you share you code or is it too secret?

Comment: How about https://jqueryui.com/dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<iframe src="your_page_url"> </iframe>
```

on your popup box.